# How to prevent a div element to scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, events, focus

I have a div element containing p elements.
I took control of the scroll position of the div (setting the scrollTop property) and of the onclick event of the p.
The problem in that when I click on a p and then I press the arrow-down or arrow-up keys, the div scrolls automatically after I did scroll it.
The div has no focus, no onkeydown or onkeypress events set...

Here is an example of code where you can apply your solution. I need to prevent the div to scroll on keypress events (arrow up and down), after I had clicked on a p.

```
<div style="height: 60px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black">
<p>Line 1</p>
<p>Line 2</p>
<p>Line 3</p>
<p>Line 4</p>
<p>Line 5</p>
<p>Line 6</p>
</div>
```

Comment: please post your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser does the scrolling for you. What you want is catching the events that lead to that scrolling before they arrive at the browser, and then cancel them.

You can catch the keydown/keyup/keypress events, and within the event handlers do (assuming jQuery)

```
$("div p").on("keydown", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/on

If you don't want to use jQuery, check the native preventDefault at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault It works like

```
document.getElementById('someId').addEventListener(
    'keyup', function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); }, false
);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't speak jQuery.

Comment: Updated. But you really should use jQuery. It'll save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Anyway I don't think your answer is relevant.

Comment: I applied the addEventListener method to my div for keyup and keypress events. It didn't work. You got perfectly my question but I didn't with your answer.

Comment: @donkeydown: Show your code, so that we can understand what you are trying